# Make tooltip display over modal in react-vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I'm working on a react project that uses the `react-vega-lite` and `vega-tooltip` packages, making a VegaLite component where

```
tooltip={new Handler().call}
```

This works in getting a tooltip to display, however my table is in a modal and the tooltip is displayed behind.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can access the css for the tooltip and set it to important?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up solving this with the following CSS:

```
#vg-tooltip-element {
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

See the docs for customizing `vega-tooltip` [here](https://github.com/vega/vega-tooltip/blob/master/docs/customizing_your_tooltip.md#customizing-the-theme).